# SKPhysicsBody "Extra argument 'size' in call"

Tags: swift, size, skphysicsbody

What I'm trying to achieve is to make a shape of the object(physical body) exactly as a texture, so that only the texture (and not the transparent layer) would be clickable in the future.

```
    let fireLayer = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: fireImage)
    fireLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0)
    fireLayer.position = CGPointMake(size.width, 0)
    fireLayer.zPosition = Layer.Z4st

    var firedown = SKAction.moveToY(-200, duration: 0)
    var fireup1 = SKAction.moveToY(10, duration: 1.2)
    var fireup2 = SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 0.2)
```

here, I'm trying to create physical body to "cut out" needed object from the node.

```
    fireLayer.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: fireLayer, size: fireLayer.texture!.size())
```

Now, here I got an error "Extra argument 'size' in call"... Although SKPhysicalBody has two parameters: texture and size.

```
    fireLayer.name = "fireNode"

    fireLayer.runAction(SKAction.sequence([firedown, wait1, fireup1, fireup2]))

    addChild(fireLayer)
```

what have I done wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is misleading. Your problem actually is the first parameter `texture: fireLayer`. You need to set a `SKTexture` and not a `SKSpriteNode`.

Also you should change the way you initialize your SKSpriteNode and add an SKTexture:

```
let fireLayerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: fireImage)
```

And than:

```
let fireLayer = SKSpriteNode(texture: fireLayerTexture)
```

After you've don that, you can initialize your `SKPhysicsBody` like that:

```
fireLayer.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: fireLayerTexture, size: fireLayer.texture!.size())
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked, I just blocked gravity.
But, when I'm touching outside the sprite, object still activates the sound:

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
for touch: AnyObject in touches {           
let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        
let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
let node: SKNode = nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
            
if node.name == "fireNode" {
                
var playguitar = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("fire.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
node.runAction(playguitar)
                
            }

Comment: sorry for a long comment